# Java Wildcard Capture failing for unknown reason

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, static-methods

In writing a static generic method to do an insertion Sort. I ran across the following wild card capture problem that I cannot solve. There is a simple solution to the problem but I still would like to know why my original attempt does not compile. I have done a similar thing for quicksort which compiles correctly.

Note: **I know that by changing the declaration from `List<? extends T> col` to `List<T> col` the code will compile and run properly**. But because I am capturing the wildcard in the "move" method below, it should also compile if I leave the 
"? extends T" as is. Does anyone have any idea why it refuses to compile? I am using jdk1.8.0_60 in Eclipse( NEON ).

Here is the relevant code that does not compile:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
    void insertionSort(List<? extends T> col) {

    for ( int i = 1 ; i < col.size(); i++ ){
        int j = i - 1 ;
        T key = col.get(i);
        while ( j > -1  && col.get(j).compareTo(key)  > 0 ) {
        T ele = col.get(j);
        InsertionSort.move(j+1,ele,col); // **DOES NOT COMPILE** 
        j = j - 1;
        }
        InsertionSort.move(j+1, key, col); // **DOES NOT COMPILE** 
    }
}

private static <T> void move(int jplus1, T key, List<T> col) {
    col.set(jplus1, key);   
}
```

I am doing a similar thing with quickSort which, believe it or not , compiles correctly.
Here is the quicksort that actually compiles correctly: Notice the **swap** method.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
void quickSort(List<? extends T> col) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(col);
    _quickSort(col, 0, col.size() - 1);
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
    void _quickSort(List<? extends T> col, int start, int end) {
    int partitionPoint = 0;
    if (start < end) {
        partitionPoint = partition(col, start, end);
        _quickSort(col, start, partitionPoint - 1);
        _quickSort(col, partitionPoint + 1, end);
    }
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
int partition(List<? extends T> col, int start, int end) {
    T pivot = col.get(end);
    int partitionIndex = start;
    for (int j = start; j <= (end - 1); j++) {
        int cmp = col.get(j).compareTo(pivot);
        if (cmp < 1) {
            swap(j, partitionIndex, col); // COMPILES CORRECTLY
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(partitionIndex, end, col);
    return partitionIndex;
}

private static <T> void swap(int j, int partitionIndex, List<T> col) {
    T temp = col.get(j);
    col.set(j, col.get(partitionIndex));
    col.set(partitionIndex, temp);
}
```

Comment: For some reason the original message was altered slightly: I tried to say that by changing List<? extends T> col  to List<T> col it will compile. But I feel that it should compile with List<? extends T> col since I capture the wildcard in the "move" method.

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a few hours ago?

Comment: nope ... yesterday was the first time I ever posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

The short version: The problem is the `T key` parameter of the `move` method.

More in depth: So you have a `? extends T` wildcard, and a `List` that contains that type. Let's call whatever the type actually is `U`. Since you are passing the list directly on, in its original type as you received it, you are calling the `<U>` version of `move`. This requires that you pass it a `List<U>` - works fine - and a `U key` - but the variable you're passing for the key is type `T`. `U` is bound as a subclass of `T`, so that's an unsafe cast.

You could alternatively be calling the `<T>` version of `move`. In that case, `T key` would be fine, but now you're trying to pass a `List<U>` as a `List<T>` and *that* is an unsafe cast. Either way you have an unsafe cast, so the compiler reports an error.

If you eliminate the intervening variable and call `move(j+1, col.get(i), col)`, I believe that would compile because the compiler can tell that the result of `col.get(i)` is of type `U`, satisfying the type signature of `move<U>`.

To show a bit more explicitly why this is a problem, let's go through an example. I'll pretend that `Number` implements `Comparable<Number>` because it makes things easier to follow. You call your sort as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
insertionSort<Number>(list);
```

Now, your code gets to the first `move` call. On that line, you have:

- First argument: `j+1`, of type `int`
- Second argument: `ele`, of type `Number`
- Third argument: `col`, of type `List<? extends Number>`

The `? extends Number` in this case happens to be `Integer`.

Now, given those arguments, what is the generic type of `move` that gets called? There are two obvious possibilities, `move<Integer>` and `move<Number>`.

`move<Integer>`: This requires a second argument (`T key`) of type `Integer`. You're giving it a variable of type `Number`. That doesn't fit, so this option doesn't work.

`move<Number>`: The second argument works fine, but now look at the third. The third argument requires type `List<Number>`. What you're passing it is `List<Integer>`. If the compiler allowed you to do that, it would mean that the `move` method would be allowed to add, say, `3.14159` to the list, which would break the list's constraint of only containing integers. Therefore that doesn't fit, so this option doesn't work.

There aren't any other relevant options to consider. So, the compiler gets to that line, tries to figure out whether it's calling `move<Integer>`, `move<Number>`, `move<String>`, or whatever else, and finds that nothing works. There is no version at all of `move` that fits all three arguments you're trying to pass to it at once, so it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still confused as to why the move will not compile if I put that wild-card in the declaration of insertionSort. It appears that the same type of method is created in the quickSort above and yet, it compiles!  I did notice one difference between the quickSort and the insertionSort in the declaration of the class containing the static methods. The quickSort has a class parameter and the insertionSort did not. So I put a class parameter in the InsertionSort class but to no avail. Still would not compile.

Comment: private static <T> void move(int jplus1,T key, List<T> col) {
---- the swap works and compiles ok ... both are structurally the same????
private static <T> void swap(int j, int partitionIndex, List<T> col) {

Comment: @GeorgeCurington The important difference between `move` and `swap` is that `move` has the `T` parameter in two different places in its arguments list, and there's no possible value for `T` that makes *both* of the parameters you call it with fit the method signature at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This compile error is caused by the Producer Extends, Consumer Super Principle : PECS [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Bottom line, your code is both a producer AND a consumer (the consumer is the `move` method) so you can't use `? extends T` because you can't do a put (or `set` in this case) using an `extends`.

**EDIT**

why does your quicksort `swap` method work then?

Notice the method signature difference

quicksort `<T> void swap(int j, int partitionIndex, List<T> col)`

vs

insertionSort  `<T> void move(int jplus1, T key, List<T> col) {`

The difference in the quicksort is you give the indexes to swap but in the insertionSort that doesn't compile you provide one of the values as a type `T`.
By just using the indexes you have to fetch the values from the list so the type `T` is a brand new inferred type.  In your insertionSort you provide an already fetched `T` value which is the wrong capture type compared to the new inferred type which can't have an `extends` in it because you are both getting and putting.

If you change your code to use just offsets it will compile but you will have to modify your method to insert differently because the way you have it you will lose the value to be inserted earlier in the list if you change it this way.

Comment: Riddle me this "bat man". Why does it work in the QuickSort example? Answer that question and you will find the solution. I have yet to figure it out. I am quite familiar with the get & put principal that you describe using the terms, Producer / Consumer et al ... but if you observe the code carefully, you will see the wildcard is being captured properly.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between swap and move is that swap does not take generic key of type T. That is what the compiler is complaining about, as described in the previous answers. Using wildcards in your methods does not make sense at all. Why do you need wildcard at all? Can't you just do this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void insertionSort(List<T> col) {
    for (int i = 1; i < col.size(); i++) {
        int j = i - 1;
        T key = col.get(i);
        while (j > -1 && col.get(j).compareTo(key) > 0) {
            T ele = col.get(j);
            move(j + 1, ele, col); // **DOES NOT COMPILE**
            j = j - 1;
        }
        move(j + 1, key, col); // **DOES NOT COMPILE**
    }
}

private static <T> void move(int jplus1, T key, List<T> col) {
    col.set(jplus1, key);
}
```

Comment: both take a generic key of type T? Not sure what you are talking about. I am curious about why it does not work? Not really interested in subjective musings, though such musings are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to overcome the problem: It requires creating an additional method to properly capture the wildcard:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertionSort(List<? extends T> col){
    _insertionSort(col,1,col.size());
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void _insertionSort(List<T> col,int start,int end){
```